# Reply Time out for StoredProcOutboundGateway

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I have issue with  reply-timeout property of StoredProcOutboundGateway in spring integration. I have gone through the documentation and it says reply-time out will not work in case of direct channel for the Gateway . But in case of external integration gateways ie StoredProcOutboundGateway it says
"when sending to a DirectChannel, the invocation will occur in the sender’s thread so the failing of the send operation may be caused by other components further downstream "

As per my design my StoredProcOutboundGateway reply is sending to a Direct channel.Will the StoredProcOutboundGateway throw exception after the reply-time out expiration ? .For re creating this scenario I have put a debug point and wait for configured reply time out in the first line of StoredProcOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage method ,But it didn't thrown any exception and it returned successsful response even after configured time   .

`<int:gateway id="idGateway" service-interface="Gateway">
<int:method name="getStoreProcData" request-channel="store.req.channel" reply-channel="store.reply.channel" />
</int:gateway>
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway stored-procedure-name="GE_PKG.GET_PRC"
        ignore-column-meta-data="true" reply-timeout="2000" request-channel="store.req.channel" reply-channel="store.reply.channel" is-function="false"
............other cursor config
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>`enter code here
`<int:channel id="store.req.channel" />
<int:channel id="store.reply.channel" />`

Spring-Integration V4..1.2 DB oracle ojdbc6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reply-timeout` only applies if the `reply-channel` can block - such as a bounded `QueueChannel` that is full.

i.e. it is a timeout for the `send` to the `reply-channel`.

It will never occur with a `DirectChannel`.

Comment: .thanks. It could have mentioned in the docs for store proc outbound gateway section